# ASP.NET one web form two input file fields

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a webform in ASP.NET and two input file fields, because the user is supposed to upload an xml file through the one file input and a video through the other. These two inputs (ids xmlurl and videourl in the code below) are in the same form. I have also two submit buttons (ids load_mp4_button and load_xml_button) that the user must press when he wants the file to be uploaded. With the first button a map must be loaded in the corresponding div and with the second one a video in the second div.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
<div id="map" class="map"  runat="server"></div>
<div id="info"  runat="server">&nbsp;</div>
<input id="xmlurl"  runat="server" type="file" accept="text/xml" name="xmlurl" />
<input id="load_xml_button"  runat="server" type="submit"  />
<input id="videourl"  runat="server" type="file" accept=".mp4" name="videourl" />
<input id="load_mp4_button"  runat="server" type="submit"  />
<video id="video"  runat="server" width="640" height="480" controls="controls">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</form>
```

I have added event listeners in c# to these two buttons, in order to convert the physical path of the file to url, and to load the map and the video.
For example, in the server side:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //add event listeners

        load_mp4_button.ServerClick += new EventHandler(this.mp4_button_clicked);
        load_xml_button.ServerClick += new EventHandler(this.xml_button_clicked);

    }

protected void mp4_button_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //request the first file
        HttpPostedFile filePosted = Request.Files["videourl"];
        string url_path1 = Path2url(filePosted);

        //do something with the file

    }
    protected void xml_button_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //request the second file
        HttpPostedFile filePosted = Request.Files["xmlurl"];

    }
```

The problem I have is that, whenever you hit the first button to load the map, and then you hit the second one to load the video, the map is gone. Although they are displayed in different divs. With pure js event listeners there is not such a problem.
Does somebody know if this is happening because these input fields are in the same form? Should I try with an asp component from the toolbox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: buttons when clicked cause postback and refresh the entire page, I would recommend to use asp updatepanels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you hit submit it sends the the form which you can the access in a POST controller if you are using MVC. So in this case both of your submits are doing the same thing which is sending the whole form including both file inputs.

Comment: Its Web Forms but also the same idea.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the answers!
I simply thought to add just one button for the two uploads